# How to find the centroid of this tricky surface?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

**Problem:** The solid bounded by the surface $z=\sin(x), x=0,x=\pi,y=0,z=0,$ and $y+z=1,$ where the density $\rho=1.$

**My Attempt:** I know that in order to find the centroid one first must compute the mass of the solid, which is given by the following expression $$m=\int\int\int \rho dxdydz.$$
However, I am unable to come up with the bounds for this triple integral. I have come up with the bounds for the variables $x$ and $y$ but for $z$ I am still confused.
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{?}^{?} \rho dxdydz$$

Any hints/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\rho(x,y,z)=1$ then this computation simplifies to be a double integral.

---

The body is bounded by $z=0$ from below and by the following function of $x$ and $y$ from above:

$$z(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\sin(x)&\text{ if }& 0\le y\le 1-\sin(x)&\text{ and }& 0\le x\le \pi\\
1-y&\text{ if }& 1-\sin(x)<y\le 1&\text{ and }& 0\le x\le \pi\\
0&\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

as it is shown in the following figure
[image]

The volume of this body (its mass if $\rho=1$) is given by the double integral

$$\iint_{[0,\pi]\times[0,1]} z(x,y)\ dx\ dy=$$
$$=\int_0^{\pi}\left[\int_0^{1-\sin(x)}\sin(x)\ dy +\int_{1-\sin(x)}^11-y\ dy\ \right]dx=$$
$$=\int_0^{\pi}\left[\sin(x)\int_0^{1-\sin(x)}\ dy +\int_{1-\sin(x)}^1\ dy-\int_{1-\sin(x)}^1y\ dy\ \right] dx=\cdots$$

Answer (score 2):

We have $0\le z\le \sin x$, $0\le x\le \pi$ and $0\le y\le1-z$.
The $y$ bounds depend on $z$. The $x$ bounds depend on $x$. So put $x$
on the outside, $z$ inside and $y$ on the very inside to get
$$\int_0^\pi\int_0^{\sin x}\int_0^{1-z}\,dy\,dz\,dx.$$